# Why is using a material AppCompat theme causing full screen?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles, material-design

I'm trying to switch over an app to use Theme.Material, I have a toolbar setup with fitsSystemWindows set to true yet my activity extends below the navigation bars!!

Here's my theme

```
 <style name="FlowTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

    <item name="cpvColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="cpvStrokeWidth">3dp</item>
    <item name="cpvCircleAnimDuration">1400</item>
    <item name="cpvSweepAnimDuration">950</item>
</style>
```

Nothing is triggerend in my activity to flag fullscreen

What's going on? how do I fix this so that it's not fullscreen?

**Edit:** Here's my main activity XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ActMain"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
    android:name="com.metalab.flow.ui.fragments.FrNavigationDrawer"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fr_navigation_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the reason

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar // i show no actionbar..
```

put this in your activity xml layout, if its `linearLayout` let it be the first child, if its `RelativeLayout` let it be on top and all children should align to it..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:theme="@style/FlowTheme" />
```

style

```
 <style name="FlowTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

<item name="cpvColor">@color/accent</item>
<item name="cpvStrokeWidth">3dp</item>
<item name="cpvCircleAnimDuration">1400</item>
<item name="cpvSweepAnimDuration">950</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Still not working, I even added ```<item name="windowActionBar">false</item> ``` to fix the setSupportActionBar(mToolbar) error

Comment: The view seems to just go below the bottom Navigation Bars for the height of the Status Bar

Comment: The view shows up beneath the status bar but it's longer that the system window so it extends beneath the navigation bars

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I was using this class, for a core WebView bug fix https://github.com/madebycm/AndroidBug5497Workaround

Removing it's use fixed my issue, however the WebView resize bug lives on...

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrap_content in your toolbar, and if you havent given support to it, then it hasn't content to show. I recomend you that change the height of the toolbar to:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

And you should give support in your java file to show the title and buttons:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

EDIT: I read some of other replies, and I add more info because I suppose that you had the toolbar defined in other xml. This is an example of toolbar that you should include:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:translationZ="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```